# What's the meaning of `show a hack`?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

When I read a article:

> Today, I’ll show a hack to keep using sketch.

What's the meaning of `show a hack`?

---

**EDIT**

I can guess the `show a hack` general meaning, but I don't know why the meaning can use `hack` to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ***hack*** in this case is a technique to do something. So if they're showing you a hack, they're showing a way you can keep using the app Sketch even though it's past its trial period. A "hack" is usually something clever and undocumented -- a trick.

Answer (score 0):

A hack in general is a technique/method/procedure that makes something easier to accomplish. I'm going to show you a math-based example that will drive the point home. What's the sum of the first 10,000 integers (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 10,000)? One way to find it would be to take a pen and a piece of paper and start adding the numbers together one by one. Another way to solve this problem would be to use the following famous formula: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n + 1)/2 which will give you the sum of the first 10,000 numbers in no time. And that's basically an example of a hack. Though, no mathematician would call it like that, but that's just an example. In other words, a hack is a way (you can even think of it as a shortcut) to solve a problem the easy way.